# Google Analytics API: auto login user and fetch data, showing error "The OAuth client was invalid."

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I want to access google analytic data using oAuth , so that I do not have to login again and again.

for that I download google analytic `Php library` , install it using `composer` , put the `code` provided by `google` , my code is below -

```
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $analytics = initializeAnalytics();
    $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
    $results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
    printResults($results);

    function initializeAnalytics()
    {
      // Creates and returns the Analytics Reporting service object.

      // Use the developers console and download your service account
      // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
      // change the key file location if necessary.
      $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'myproject.json';

      // Create and configure a new client object.
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
      $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
      $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);

      $analytics  = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

      return $analytics;
    }

    function getFirstProfileId($analytics) {
        // Get the user's first view (profile) ID.
        // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
        $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();


      if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

        // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
        $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
            ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
          $items = $properties->getItems();
          $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

          // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
          $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
              ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

          if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $profiles->getItems();

            // Return the first view (profile) ID.
            return $items[0]->getId();

          } else {
            throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
          }
        } else {
          throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
        }
      } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
      }
    }

    function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
      // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
      // for the last seven days.
       return $analytics->data_ga->get(
           'ga:' . $profileId,
           '7daysAgo',
           'today',
           'ga:sessions');
    }

    function printResults($results) {
      // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
      // the profile name and total sessions.
      if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

        // Get the profile name.
        $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

        // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $sessions = $rows[0][0];

        // Print the results.
        print "First view (profile) found: $profileName\n";
        print "Total sessions: $sessions\n";
      } else {
        print "No results found.\n";
      }
    }
```

When I used to run this code it providing below error -

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "The OAuth client was invalid." } in D:\wamp64\www\store2\pdf\printpdf\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 118

Basically, if anybody can provide me a step by step process of accessing data from google analytics, because I roll out my head whole day, but there is not a single post which can provide me steps to follow, some which I found are old , and not working for me

Comment: is the key file in the current path?  Did you create service account credentials?

Comment: yes, what I did, is - open console https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials , "Google Cloud Platform", In left Tab got option "I am & admin" -> Service Accounts , I generated a service account , which provided me a JSON which is being added as "myproject.json", `$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'myproject.json';`

Answer (score 1):

This is the code i use

**Serviceaccount.php**

```
    // Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Use the developers console and download your service account
// credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
// change the key file location if necessary.
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__.'/service-account.json');
$service = getAuthenticateServiceAccount();


/**
 * Authenticating to Google using a Service account
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
 * Initializes an Analyticsreporting.v4 service object.
 *
 * @return An authorized Analyticsreporting.v4 service object.
 */
function getAuthenticateServiceAccount() {
    try {   

        // Create and configure a new client object.        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS);
        return new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

**Reporting.php**

```
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/ServiceAccount.php';

// Create the DateRange object.
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("2016-01-01");
$dateRange->setEndDate("2017-06-30");

// Create the Metrics object.
$sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
$sessions->setAlias("ga:sessions");

$users = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$users->setExpression("ga:users");
$users->setAlias("ga:users");



//Create the Dimensions object.
$date = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$date->setName("ga:date");
$pagePath = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$pagePath->setName("ga:pagePath");

// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId("81692014");
$request->setPageSize("10000");
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setDimensions(array($date,$pagePath));
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions,$users));

$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
$data =  $service->reports->batchGet( $body );


showData($data->reports[0]);
$cnt = 0; 
while ($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken > 0 && $cnt < 1) {
    // There are more rows for this report.
    $body->reportRequests[0]->setPageToken($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken);
    $data =  $service->reports->batchGet( $body );
    showData($data->reports[0]);
    $cnt++;
    }



function showData($data)  {
    ?> <pre><table><?php

    ?><tr><?php // Header start row
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data->columnHeader->dimensions);$i++)  {
        ?> <td> <?php print_r($data->columnHeader->dimensions[$i]); ?> </td> <?php
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data->columnHeader->metricHeader->metricHeaderEntries);$i++)   {
        ?> <td> <?php print_r($data->columnHeader->metricHeader->metricHeaderEntries[$i]->name); ?> </td> <?php
    }
    ?><tr><?php  // Header row end

    // Display data
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data->data->rows);$i++)    {

        ?><tr><?php // Data row start
        // Dimensions
        for($d = 0; $d < sizeof($data->columnHeader->dimensions);$d++)  {
            ?> <td> <?php print_r($data->data->rows[$i]->dimensions[$d]); ?> </td> <?php
        }
        // Metrics
        for($m = 0; $m < sizeof($data->columnHeader->metricHeader->metricHeaderEntries);$m++)   {
            ?> <td> <?php print_r($data->data->rows[$i]->metrics[0]->values[$m]); ?> </td> <?php
        }
        ?><tr><?php  // Header row end
    }
    ?></table></pre><?php
}


function showText($data)
{
 ?> <pre> <?php print_r($data); ?> </pre> <?php
}
/**
* Returns the Analytics data. 
* Documentation https://developers.google.com/analyticsreporting/v4/reference/reports/batchGet
* Generation Note: This does not always build corectly.  Google needs to standardise things I need to figuer out which ones are wrong.
* @service Authenticated Analyticsreporting service.</param>  
* @body A valid Analyticsreporting v4 body.</param>
* @return GetReportsResponseResponse</returns>
*/
function BatchGet($service, $body)
{
    try
    {
        // Initial validation.
        if ($service == null)
            throw new Exception("service");
        if ($body == null)
            throw new Exception("body");

        // Make the request.
        return $service->reports->batchGet($body);
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Request Reports.BatchGet failed.", $ex->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

**Update**:

Remember to make sure you granted the service account assess to your Google analytics account at the account level.

[image]

Note code was ripped from my [github](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/1bdf5d6259c161c5bff35db0c01710da) project

Comment: `Remember to make sure you granted the service account assess to your Google analytics account at the account level.`, please share some more description, if you can share some sample snapshots will help me , I tried your above code , and showing blank

Comment: The above code creates the analytics service just like your initializeAnalytics function.   You need to go to the google analytics website in the admin section and take the service account email address and add it as a user at the account level in order to grant it access to your google analytics account.

Comment: The email which I get in service account , I added it `Google Analytics -> User management` section , but still same result

Comment: at the account level?

Comment: ok , now I am getting result from your code , so what should i do with this one , because this initialization was already happening before , the issue was coming , when I was using the object in `function getFirstProfileId($analytics) `

Comment: Hey @DalmTo , Please let me know , how I can get google analytics data using `Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting` object

Comment: $service returned by getAuthenticateServiceAccount() is the analytics service which you can send all of your request though.  In your code you call it $analytics i find it makes more seance calling it $service.

Comment: This shows returning data.   but you might want to check out https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154801/discussion-between-amit-game-and-daimto).